# Poor quality reviews

Tags: discussion, support, review-queue

I'm trying to determine how [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/267814/34147) could have *possibly* made it through the "First Question" review queue without *any* sort of comment or flag.

Let's be honest, this question is absolute rubbish, doesn't fit the format here, and doesn't even ask a question! Just in case it does happen to get edited before you've read it, here's a screen capture of the question as it was originally posted:

[image]

And here's the history, showing that it received two reviews stating "Looks OK" followed by my note that it does *not* in *any way*, "look ok".

[image]

I have no idea what, if anything can be done about this, but I definitely want to bring it to the attention of the community and mods. It seems that some people aren't putting any thought whatsoever into their review efforts and are simply clicking buttons, perhaps in pursuit of a badge or a ranking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only takes one review to get out of the queue. I've taken note of where that came from. If it turns out to be a pattern, the mods can suspend their access to reviews. Let us know if you see similar issues.

Comment: Will do, thanks. I've noticed a lot of questionable 1st questions that have up votes, most likely (IMHO) because the "Look OK" response also prompts to "vote accordingly". I'll keep an eye out and report any back here.

Comment: @FreeMan I've seen additional poor reviews from the same reviewer and have taken action. Thank you for raising this issue.